# How to loop through a list of lists, whilst subsetting the lists based on a variable

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a list of lists similar to the toy example given here. I would like to loop through this list to return a new list which has had elements removed based on a variable.

---

dput(head(list)):

```
list(FEB_gems = list(GAME1 = structure(list(GAME1_Class = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("fighter", "paladin", "rouge", "sorcerer", 
"wizard"), class = "factor"), GAME1_Race = structure(c(3L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("elf", "gnome", "human", "orc"), class = "factor"), 
GAME1_Alignment = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("CE", 
"CG", "LG", "NE", "NN"), class = "factor"), GAME1_Level = c(6, 
7, 6, 7, 7), GAME1_Alive = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = "y", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)), GAME2 = structure(list(GAME2_Class = structure(c(3L, 5L, 
2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("bard", "cleric", "fighter", "monk", 
"wizard"), class = "factor"), GAME2_Race = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("dwarf", "elf", "half-elf", "human"), class = "factor"), 
GAME2_Alignment = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("CE", 
"CG", "LG", "NE", "NN"), class = "factor"), GAME2_Level = c(5, 
5, 5, 5, 5), GAME2_Alive = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("n", "y"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))), MAR_gems = list(GAME3 = structure(list(GAME3_Class = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("barbarian", "cleric", "monk", "ranger", 
"warlock"), class = "factor"), GAME3_Race = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("dwarf", "elf", "half-elf", "human"), class = "factor"), 
GAME3_Alignment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("CE", 
"LG", "LN"), class = "factor"), GAME3_Level = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), GAME3_Alive = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("n", 
"y"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)), GAME4 = structure(list(GAME4_Class = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("fighter", "paladin", "rouge", "sorcerer", 
"wizard"), class = "factor"), GAME4_Race = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("dwarf", "elf", "half-elf", "human"), class = "factor"), 
GAME4_Alignment = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("CE", 
"CG", "LG", "LN"), class = "factor"), GAME4_Level = c(5, 
5, 5, 5, 5), GAME4_Alive = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("n", "y"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))))
```

---

I have made some attempt at manually sub-setting the list of lists. A function would be preferable is because I have multiple types of data to subset.

1) sub-setting Level columns based on interger

```
df1 <- Games.Split[[1]][[1]]
Level <- df1[which(df1[4] > 6),]
Games.Split[[1]][[1]] <- Level
```

df1:

```
  GAME1_Class GAME1_Race GAME1_Alignment GAME1_Level GAME1_Alive
1     paladin      human              NE           6           y
2     fighter        elf              CG           7           y
3      wizard        orc              CE           6           y
4    sorcerer      human              NN           7           y
5       rouge      gnome              LG           7           y
```

Level:

```
 GAME1_Class GAME1_Race GAME1_Alignment GAME1_Level GAME1_Alive
2     fighter        elf              CG           7           y
4    sorcerer      human              NN           7           y
5       rouge      gnome              LG           7           y
```

2) sub-setting Alive columns based on string

```
df2 <- Games.Split[[1]][[2]]
Alive <- df2[which(df2[5] == 'y'),]
Games.Split[[1]][[2]] <- Alive
```

df2:

```
 GAME2_Class GAME2_Race GAME2_Alignment GAME2_Level GAME2_Alive
1     fighter        elf              NE           5           n
2      wizard   half-elf              CG           5           y
3      cleric        elf              CE           5           y
4        monk      human              NN           5           y
5        bard      dwarf              LG           5           y
```

Alive:

```
 GAME2_Class GAME2_Race GAME2_Alignment GAME2_Level GAME2_Alive
2      wizard   half-elf              CG           5           y
3      cleric        elf              CE           5           y
4        monk      human              NN           5           y
5        bard      dwarf              LG           5           y
```

However I'm struggling to put this into action in a for loop to perform these sub-setting tasks on the entire list.

```
for (i in Games.Split){
  for (j in i){
    Alive = j[which(j[5] == 'y'),]
    j <- Alive
  }
}
```

---

Overall, a function/ method that can iterate through the whole list to provide a new list which no longer has the removed elements.

Comment: Do you want it to store it on different lists.  Then you can do `library(purrr); map(lst1, '[[', 1); map(lst1, '[[', 2)`

Comment: I would rather make a new list in a similar structure to the original.

Comment: Can you check the posted solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have two levels of lists to organizing the dataframes, this will require a nested list apply function (`lapply`)-- same as a loop but a little neater. Here is an example that creates a function to subset the game list (gameList) based on maximum level (maxLevel):

```
listSubset <- function(x, maxLevel){
  lapply(x, function(ls){
    lapply(ls, function(df) df[df[[grep('Level', names(df), value = TRUE)]] < maxLevel, ])
  })
}
listSubset(x = gameList, maxLevel = 6)
```

Output:

```
$`FEB_gems`
$`FEB_gems`$`GAME1`
[1] GAME1_Class     GAME1_Race      GAME1_Alignment GAME1_Level     GAME1_Alive    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`FEB_gems`$GAME2
  GAME2_Class GAME2_Race GAME2_Alignment GAME2_Level GAME2_Alive
1     fighter        elf              NE           5           n
2      wizard   half-elf              CG           5           y
3      cleric        elf              CE           5           y
4        monk      human              NN           5           y
5        bard      dwarf              LG           5           y


$MAR_gems
$MAR_gems$`GAME3`
  GAME3_Class GAME3_Race GAME3_Alignment GAME3_Level GAME3_Alive
1      cleric        elf              LG           1           y
2   barbarian   half-elf              LG           1           y
3     warlock        elf              CE           1           y
4      ranger      human              LN           1           n
5        monk      dwarf              LG           1           y

$MAR_gems$GAME4
  GAME4_Class GAME4_Race GAME4_Alignment GAME4_Level GAME4_Alive
1     paladin        elf              CE           5           n
2     fighter   half-elf              CG           5           y
3      wizard        elf              CE           5           y
4    sorcerer      human              LN           5           y
5       rouge      dwarf              LG           5           y
```

All the functions are in base R, so no need to install and learn new packages.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only two nested `list`s, and want different `filter`ing conditions, apply on it individually and assign the output back to the `list` element.  We loop through the master `list` with `map` and then apply the logical conditions

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
lst2 <- map(lst1, ~  {
       .x[[1]] <- .x[[1]] %>%
                       filter_at(4, all_vars(. > 6))
       .x[[2]] <- .x[[2]] %>%
                      filter_at(5, all_vars(. == 'y'))
         .x
    })
```

Comment: For some reason, on my end, the nested list 'GAME3_' was entirely removed by this method. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that life would be easier if you restructure your data, then use `dplyr`'s `filter` to pull out what you want (or omit what you don't want). Assuming your original data is called `foo`:

```
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Remove one list
bar <- unlist(foo, recursive = FALSE)

# Get names of campaigns and games
campaign_games <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(bar), "\\.")))

# Add campaigns and games numbers to data frames
ls_games <- pmap(list(campaign_games[, 1], campaign_games[, 2], bar), cbind)

# Rename all columns
ls_games <-  lapply(ls_games, function(x){names(x) <- c("Campaign", "Game_n", "Class", "Race", "Alignment", "Level", "Alive"); x})

# Convert to data frame
df <- bind_rows(ls_games)

# Look at result
head(df)
```

Now your data looks like this:

```
#   Campaign Game_n    Class  Race Alignment Level Alive
# 1 FEB_gems  GAME1  paladin human        NE     6     y
# 2 FEB_gems  GAME1  fighter   elf        CG     7     y
# 3 FEB_gems  GAME1   wizard   orc        CE     6     y
# 4 FEB_gems  GAME1 sorcerer human        NN     7     y
# 5 FEB_gems  GAME1    rouge gnome        LG     7     y
# 6 FEB_gems  GAME2  fighter   elf        NE     5     n
```

which is easy to handle. For example, pull those that are alive in game 1 of FEB gems and are level 7 or higher.

```
df %>% filter(Alive == "y", Campaign == "FEB_gems", 
              Level >= 7, Game_n == "GAME1")

#   Campaign Game_n    Class  Race Alignment Level Alive
# 1 FEB_gems  GAME1  fighter   elf        CG     7     y
# 2 FEB_gems  GAME1 sorcerer human        NN     7     y
# 3 FEB_gems  GAME1    rouge gnome        LG     7     y
```